# gnome configuration to enable "raise on click" for a window in Redhat Linux 6

Tags: linux, gnome

How to get the configuration editor in RHEL 6.

I need this to set the property raise_on_click to true

RHEL 4:
This could be done via GUI Configuration Editor
Applications -> System Tools -> Configuration Editor
Go in apps -> metacity

RHEL 7: 
gsettings tool is available to set the raise on click property
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences raise-on-click false

In RHEL 6 the tool gsettings in not avaiable

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable raise on click window property key in Rehdat Linux perform following steps:

RHEL 4:

1. This could be done via GUI Configuration Editor Applications -> System Tools -> Configuration Editor Go in 
   apps -> metacity -> rhel3_workarounds
   set the property "raise_on_click"

RHEL 6:

Use gconftool-2

gconftool-2 --type boolean --set /apps/metacity/general/auto_raise true

RHEL 7:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences raise-on-click true

Please give me more details as to what was not clear in the question.